# In Coded UI, is there any way to specify IP/Hostname of Agent machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, distributed-testing

In Coded UI, is there any way to specify IP/Hostname of Agent machine in which the test needs to be run?
For example : If I want to run method1 on Agent 1 and method2 on Agent 2 and so on. I can be able run the tests using "Test Controller-Test Agent" setup though. But, I want some tests to be run in specific machines and the 
other machines needs to be waited for the current test run to be completed. (method2 should wait till completion of method1)
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a Lab Environment with SCVMM?

Comment: Hi  Charles Oppermann, Currently I am not using SCVMM. If there're any solution for the above mentioned scenario, i can probably go for that. Please let me know the solution asap as I am experiencing this as a blocking issue. Thanks lot.

Comment: It's a complex subject and requires a lot of understanding of what you are working to accomplish.  Have you read "Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio"?  That's where it's all laid out.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380